# Data transfer is making my mesh become dark in colour

Tags: modifiers

I'm doing a data transfer from one object to another and its making the data transfer become extremally dark-shady.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here's the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=BZdPO5qp" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/BZdPO5qp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is set to "Shade Auto Smooth" and it's making the cylinder look like that for some reason. Just setting it to "Shade Smooth" fixes the issue.